# Solve three letter string into regular expression way

Tags: finite-automata, automata, state-machine, automata-theory

I need help to solve in regular expression way. `The language of all strings defined over Σ = {X, Y, Z} with Y as the third letter and Z being the second last letter`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are allowed to use intersection (which does preserve rationality), I would state it simply as `ΣΣYΣ* & Σ*ZΣ`.  If you feed this to [Vcsn](http://vcsn-sandbox.lrde.epita.fr) to normalize it, you get:

```
In [1]: import vcsn

In [2]: vcsn.B.expression('([XYZ]{2}Y[XYZ]*)&([XYZ]*Z[XYZ])').derived_term().expression()
Out[2]: (X+Y+Z)ZY+(X+Y+Z)(X+Y+Z)Y(X+Y+Z)*Z(X+Y+Z)
```

The call to `derived_term` is to build an automaton from the expression, and the last call to `expression` is to extract a rational expression from this automaton.

Answer (score 1):

As given Σ = {X, Y, Z} , you need to construct the language of all strings defined over it with Y as third letter and Z being the second last letter.

> "ΣΣYΣ*ZΣ | ΣZY" will be the required regular expression.

Σ* has all strings that are 0 or more concatenations of strings from Σ.

As you can see, here Y being the third element and Z is placed in second last position. And, Σ can be replaced with any of the X,Y or Z element.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't comprehend your statement @akim. Would you be please more specific? OR point at the exact error according to you.

Comment: For instance `XZY` is correct.  Your solution includes only "long" answers, but misses the case where the second to last letter is actually before the third one.  The right answer is `ΣZY|ΣΣYΣ*ZΣ`.

Comment: Thanks @akim. By the way you should have edited my answer to reflect that, editing for correction is always ''most welcome'' from my side. :)

Answer (score -1):

i think regular expression should be like this....

```
(x+y+z)zy(x+y+z)^*
```